# Page_Load question

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this javascript modal which I want to use for error reporting. Everything works well only that the code gets executed before page load. So the result is that I have my javascript before the head tag  which means nothing gets executed!

Any help?

```
public void showError(string error)
{
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.4;jQuery.facebox(\""+error+"\");</script>";        
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(script);        
}
```

By the way, my ShowError method is within a class called ErrorDisplay
This is how I call it:

```
string strErr = "error here";
            ErrorDisplay myError = new ErrorDisplay();
            myError.ShowError(strErr);
```

Comment: A little code would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieved it:

```
public void ShowError(Page CurrentPage,string error)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("$.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.4;");
    sb.AppendFormat("jQuery.facebox('{0}');", error);
    sb.Append("</script>");

    Type t = this.GetType();

    CurrentPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(t, "ErrorScript", sb.ToString());
}
```

When I call it(this,"error string");

Thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that you need to make your Javascript wait for the DOM to be ready before it executes.

The easiest way around this is to use the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method to execute your code rather than add it to the page directly:

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type myType = this.GetType();
    string script = "<script>alert('Hello World! I am ready.');</script>";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(myType, "StartupScript", script);
}
```

**UPDATE**

My example was based on the fact that your original question was specifically about Page_Load. The code only needs to be modified slightly to fit your example though:

```
public void ShowError(string error)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    s.Append("$.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.4;");
    s.AppendFormat("$.facebox('{0}');", error);
    s.Append("</script>");

    Type t = this.GetType();
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(t, "ErrorScript", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: OK, let me explain a bit. I have a class that displays errors on my page. All I do is pass the string and it shows the error. Would this code still work? How do I access the this.GetType from a class?

Comment: @Kenyana - Modify your original post with an example of your code. As of now, I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: Look at my sample code. Sometimes I don't necessarily want to execute it on page load but when some function is called e.t.c.

Comment: I am getting this:

System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Its showing an error on:

s.AppendFormat("$.facebox('{0}');");

Comment: I am also trying to find where you have: jQuery.facebox(\""+error+"\"); 
on your stringbuilder!

Comment: @Kenyana: `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()` does the same as `StringBuilder.Append(String.Format())` see MSDN

Comment: I pasted this and also changed the s.append to sb.append but my page does not show any error. Checking the source code reveals nothing like the string that I am supposed to call. Even If I declare and call the function on page.load.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your just looking to have the code in Page_Load called later try using the **Page_PreRender** method instead. 
You can find a list of events and the order they are called located here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx